# How to export a 'reactable' table to an image (PDF,JPG,PNG, or HTML page?) in R?

Tags: r, export

I have created a beautiful table in R using the 'reactable' pkg/function. I can export (in effect, knit) it as an HTML page, but is there a way to export it as an image (and if so, automatically)?
Not necessary, but here is some code:

```
x<-as.data.frame(list(a=c("why","can't","I","figure","this","out"),b=c("it","is","probably","something","really","simple"))) 
reactable(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of saving a Reactable table as an HTML file using `saveWidget` then using that file and `webshot2` to create a .png. Does this help?

```
library("reactable")
library("htmlwidgets")
library("webshot2")

html_file <- "table.html"
img_file <- "img.png"

df <- mtcars[1:3, 1:3]

table <- reactable(df)
saveWidget(widget = table, file = html_file, selfcontained = TRUE)
webshot(url = html_file, file = img_file, delay = 0.1, vwidth = 1245)
```

Comment: If you find the answer helpful please consider marking it as correct and voting.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried but this should work. `reactable` generate a `htmlwidget`. So you can use the `saveWidget` function of the `htmlwidgets` package to save the table in a html file, then use the `webshot` package to take a snapshot.

```
library(reactable)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)

rtable <- reactable(iris[1:8,])
html <- "rtable.html"
saveWidget(rtable, html)
webshot(html, "rtableSnapshot.png") # you can also export to pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! However, it throws errors:
Auto configuration failed (then a string of error codes)
Error in webshot(html, "pretty_Table_1.png") : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1

Comment: Hi again! turns out this code works once the phantomJS() function is properly installed in webshot pkg. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply `reactablefmtr::save_reactable(x, "x.png")`